# I've inherited a web page and I want to create a hover drop down menu but I'm having some trouble.

Tags: css, menu, hover

Basically I've started as webmaster for my society. I'm tryign to clean up the navigation bar and I'd like to include a drop down menu but I can't figure it out with what I have there now. The current menu looks as follows:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="home"><a <?=nlink($page, "home")?> href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li id="ourshows"><a <?=nlink($page, "shows")?> href="shows">Our Shows</a></li>
            <li id="booking"><a <?=nlink($page, "booking")?> href="booking">Booking</a></li>
            <li id="rehearsals"><a <?=nlink($page, "rehearsals")?> href="rehearsals">Rehearsals</a></li>
            <li id="history"><a <?=nlink($page, "history")?> href="history">History</a></li>
            <li id="contact"><a <?=nlink($page, "contact")?> href="contact">Committee &amp; Contact</a></li>
            <li id="involved"><a <?=nlink($page, "involved")?> href="involved">Get Involved</a></li>
            <li id="calendar"><a <?=nlink($page, "calendar")?> href="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is what my CSS looks like for this section:

```
nav {
border-top: thin #ccc solid;
border-bottom: thin #ccc solid;
font-size: 1.2em;
}

nav > ul > li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
color: black;
margin-right: 1.5rem;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
color: #555;
}

nav a:active {
color: #555;
}

nav a:visited {
color: #555;
}


nav a:focus {
color: #555;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #000;
}

nav a.selected {
font-weight: bold;
}

p:first-letter {
font-size: 120%;
}
```

Comment: You might consider a ready made wordpress template if your web development expertise is low

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this:

```css
nav {
    border-top: thin #ccc solid;
    border-bottom: thin #ccc solid;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
}
nav a:active {
    color: #555;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: #555;
}
nav a:focus {
    color: #555;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
nav a.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
p:first-letter {
    font-size: 120%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;/*hide nested ul*/
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;/*show nested ul on hover*/
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="home"> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="ourshows"><a href="shows">Our Shows</a>
          <ul>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="booking"><a href="booking">Booking</a>

        </li>
        <li id="rehearsals"><a href="rehearsals">Rehearsals</a>

        </li>
        <li id="history"><a href="history">History</a>

        </li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="contact">Committee &amp; Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li id="involved"><a href="involved">Get Involved</a>

        </li>
        <li id="calendar"><a href="calendar">Calendar</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="home">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example of a navigation with dropdown menus:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o918qho6/)

---

Basically, it uses strictly CSS to determine whether or not to show the submenus. Let me explain.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
<ul> //Outer menu
    <li> //Menu item
        <ul> //Submenu
            <li> //Submenu item
```

So to show a submenu, you add a child `<ul>` to any `<li>` in the parent menu.

---

The submenu `<ul>` is set with the following properties:

```
body > ul li ul
{
    position: absolute; /*We are taking the submenu out of the flow of the doc.*/
    top: 100%; /*Move it just below the parent <li>*/
    left: 0; /*Align to the left of the parent*/

    display: none; /*Hide it when not active*/
}
```

*Note that these are just the **important** properties. I added some others for colors and such in the actual fiddle.*

---

We then use the `:hover` property to show the submenu when necessary.

```
body > ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block; /*Show the ul*/
}
```

BAM! You have a dropdown menu. Comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This is where I'm having problems. I tried this before but when I do it ignores the hover and it just shows my subheadings as a bulleted list and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Could it be something hidden elsewhere in the code that's affecting this?

Comment: There's a million and one things that *could* be wrong. If you can provide a link to the page, I'll see if I can help you further.